# How to use URL Params plugin with Paypal Add-on

Tags: php, paypal, wordpress

I'm using the Paypal Add-on for payment section on my website. It's working fine and redirecting back to my page, What I need is, I should show the payment details and the client details on this page. I have no idea how to use this return back url to get the details. can u help me? thanks,

This is the plugin

[url params plugin](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/url-params)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you should first enable PDT in your PayPal account. Once enabled, you will be able to see transaction parameters in the return URL. See here for more details -
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/

1) Without plugin:
Once you are redirected back to your site after making payment, you can fetch the data from URL using $_GET or $_REQUEST.

e.g.

```
<?php echo $_GET['tx']; //to display the transaction ID ?>
```

This will work even without using the url params plugin.

2) Same example with url params plugin:

You can use the shortcode in following way to display the data (Note: The page where you put this shortcode, should be the page where you are redirected from PayPal after making payment)

e.g.

```
[urlparam param="tx" /] //inside WP editor
```

Comment: The thing is I'm getting only one parameter through the URL. This is my URL: http://myDomainName.com/events/?id=event_one&gf_paypal_return=aWRzPTd8NDQmaGFzaD00ODgwNDdjN2ZkNmY1ZmRhN2Q1OGE5NTYwZDA4NzJhYg%3d

Comment: Have you enabled PDT in your PayPal merchant account?

Comment: I'm testing through sandbox, yes I had enabled PDT. Where should I setup my Identity Token to the plugin?

Comment: which PayPal add on are you using?

Comment: this is my plugin:- [link]http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/PayPal_Add-On